# No se registran los datos en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, formularios

```js
<?php
  
$X = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");//or die("<h2>NO se encuentra el servidor </h2>"); 
//mysqli_select_db("abogados",$X) or die("<h2>error conexion </h2>"); 
if(!$X){
   die("<h2>NO se encuentra el servidor </h2>");
}
else {
    $nombre=$_POST['first_name'];
 $password=$_POST['passwd'];
 $repass=$_POST['repass'];
 $appaterno=$_POST['last_name'];
 $apmaterno=$_POST['last_name2'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $direccion=$_POST['addres'];
 $fec_nac=$_POST['date'];
 $nickname=$_POST['nick'];
 $celular=$_POST['movil'];
 
}
 
 
if($password!=$repass){ 
 die("<h2>contraseñas diferentes </h2>");
 } 
//$r= "INSERT INTO persona values ('$nombre','$appaterno','$apmaterno','$email','$fec_nac','$direccion','$celular','$nickname')";
// echo $r;

 mysqli_query($X,"INSERT INTO persona (nombre,appaterno,apmaterno,email,fec_nac,direccion,celular,nickname) VALUES('$nombre','$appaterno','$apmaterno','$email','$fec_nac','$direccion','$celular','$nickname')"); // or die("<h2>error de envio</h2");
 
 mysqli_query($X,"INSERT INTO usuario (nicknaname,email,password) VALUES ('$nickname','$$email','$password')"); // or die("<h2>error de envio</h2");
   
 mysqli_close($X);
      echo'se a registrado';
```

```html
</style>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
     <fieldset>
        <form action="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/alta.php" method="POST">
                <legend>Registro</legend>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Nombres(s)" required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name2" placeholder="Apellido Materno" required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Contrasenia" required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" name="repass" placeholder="Confirma contrasenia" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="addres" placeholder="Direccion" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Fecha de  nacimiento" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <input type="varchar" name="movil" placeholder="Celular" required/>
                </div>
    <div>
                
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>    
        </form>
  </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Es correcta la ruta en el `action` de tu formulario: **`action="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/alta.php"`** ? ¿Probaste si están llegando los datos, haciendo en PHP algo como `var_dump($_POST);`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Tres cosas. La primera en el formulario, como te ha apuntado el compañero en los comentarios. En el `action` estás llamado a un script php. Deberías llamarlo por `http` (si usas la ruta absoluta), o por ruta relativa. Algo así:

```
<form action="http://localhost.com/alta.php" method="post">
```

o bien

```
<form action="alta.php" method="post">
```

Esta última opción sólo si el formulario y el script están en la misma ruta. Si no, deberás poner la ruta relativa desde el formulario al script. En todo caso, un PHP no se puede llamar por `file://`.

Corregido esto, vamos a lo siguiente, que tb te han puesto en el comentario: en el script pon un `var_dump($_POST);`, sólo para asegurarte de que las variables estén pasando. Se que suena a tontería, pero está bien asegurarse.

Por último, el testigo clásico cuando una consulta debe funcionar, y no lo hace. Debajo de la línea en la que usas `mysqli_query(...)` pon lo siguiente:

```
echo mysqli_errno($X)." **** ".mysqli_error($X)."<br>";
```

Ni te imaginas los cientos de veces que esa línea me ha dicho exactamente donde estaba cometiendo un error (un nombre de campo mal puesto, una coma de más o de menos en la consulta,...). Esa línea te ayudará en muchos scripts.

Como consejo final, si puedes ve dejando a un lado mysqli y decántate por PDO.

Espero haberte ayudado.